# Twitter Bootstrap Rails: Saving when I click "NEW"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, controller, mongoid, save

I'm having problems while creating a Member (for a table).  Everytime I click 'New Member', to create one, it saves a new member automatically as if I had clicked 'Submit'. Each time I reload the page while adjusting the form, a member is created too.
It may be an typo on my controller. Here's the 'def new'.

```
def new
  @member = Member.new
  @member.association_id = @association.id
  @member.save
  3.times { @member.submembers << Submember.new() }
end
```

Otherwise it may be an error with some script.
The question is, how can I fix this?

Thank you.

If any other info is needed just comment here.

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Problem:
Calling Document.find with nil is invalid.
Summary:
Document.find expects the parameters to be 1 or more ids, and will return a single document if 1     id is provided, otherwise an array of documents if multiple ids are provided.
Resolution:
Most likely this is caused by passing parameters directly through to the find, and the parameter    either is not present or the key from which it is accessed is incorrect.
```

Comment: I'm creating Members to include in a table, the only matter is that it is creating a member automatically when I access the Form to submit a new Member.
I only need to make it stop saving these 'members', that are automatically created, to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should not save member in new action. You code should look like:

```
def new
  @member = Member.new      
  3.times { @member.submembers << Submember.new() }
end
```

And form should submit to create action, in which you save your model with association_id:

```
def create
  @member = Member.new(params[:member])
  @member.association_id = @association.id
  if @member.save
    redirect_to members_path, :notice => "Member was successfully created"
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: I've tried this now, but all I get is a MongoID error, has something to do with the check_access_parent line. I'll put the error message on the question up here.

Comment: Member has_many documents? It might be a problem with form(params from form is not valid). Member and Document is MongoID models? Which line cause this error? @member.save in create?